# Is there a way I can delay a script until everything is loaded?

Tags: jquery, caching, loading, preload

Is there a way I can postpone my jQuery script until the fonts, images, CSS, and everything else has completely loaded? I was thinking of just putting a 1 second delay on it, but is there a more accurate method?

Comment: Like by using window.onload?

Comment: ↑↑↑ `$(window).on('load', function(){$.getScript('path/to/js');});`?  Or set `defer` attribute of `script` element